# defining variables in python classes

Tags: python, class, variables

There is a code where variable is defined as follows:

```
class MoveSquareClass(object):

    # create messages that are used to publish feedback/result
    _feedback = TestFeedback()
    _result   = TestResult()

    def __init__(self):
    # code continues
```

My question what will happen when we create an instance of the class, will the variables be declared? I understand that defining the variables inside the constructor would simplify things but this was how the code was. Also should we call them using .init prefix? If yes, why?

Comment: The *class attributes* are *defined* as soon as the class is defined. Whether they *should* be class attributes or instance attributes depends on how the class will be used; it's impossible to say from this snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_feedback` and `_result` objects are created *once*, when the `MoveSquareClass` class is created. They will be shared between all subsequent instances of `MoveSquareClass`. If they were created inside `__init__` instead, they wouldn't be shared objects any more; each instance of `MoveSquareClass` would get its own instance of `TestFeedback` and `TestResult`. This could very well result in a significant change in behaviour - so you should be wary about changing it if you don't fully understand the code.